# Scala Future with Option()

Tags: scala, future, scala-option

I'm creating three actor tasks using future, and then trying to collect all three when finished.
The current code is the following:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
  val result1 = actor1 ? DataForActor(data)
  val result2 = actor2 ? DataForActor(data)
  val result3 = actor3 ? DataForActor(data)
  val answer = for {
    a <- result1.mapTo[List[ResultData]]
    b <- result2.mapTo[List[ResultData]]
    c <- result3.mapTo[List[ResultData]]
  } yield (a ++ b ++ c).sorted
  answer onComplete {
    case Success(resultData) =>
      log.debug("All actors completed succesffully")
      successActor ! SuccessData(resultData.take(2))
    case Failure(resultData) =>
      log.info("actors failed")
  }
```

Each of the actors (actor1, actor2, actor3) manipulates the data and returns either None or Option(List(resultData)), as shown in the following code:

```
val resultData = if(data.size == 0) None else {
  data.map {
    ...
    try {
      ... //manipulation on resultData
      Option(resultData)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }
  }.flatten
}
```

The for statement concatenates lists from each actor, and produces a long List(resultData).

I want that in the case that one actor returns None, it's result in the for statement will not add anything to the concatenation, i.e. List().

An example:

If I get:
    result1 = List(1, 2, 3),
    result2 = None,
    result3 = List(4, 5),

I want:
    resultData = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: Try to return same type in any case. You should either return `Nil` instead of `None` or use `Option[List[ResultData]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace `None` with `Nil` before `mapTo` this way:

```
result1.map{
  case None => Nil
  case x => x
}.mapTo[List[ResultData]]
```

Note that you should avoid `mapTo` with generic type like `List`:

```
Future("x" :: Nil).mapTo[List[Int]]
// res0: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]]

Future("x" :: Nil).mapTo[List[Int]] foreach { _.map( _ + 1 ) }
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Because of type erasure `mapTo` can't prove that you have list of `Int`, not `List` of some other type. You'll get the same problem with `case l: List[Int]` in `receive` method of actor.

You should create special class for your messages like this:

```
sealed trait ResultList { def data: List[ResultData] }
case class NotEmptyResult(data: List[ResultData]) extends ResultList 
case object EmptyResult extends ResultList { def data: List[ResultData] = Nil }

result1.mapTo[ResultList]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. As for your comment regarding mapTo with List generics, what would you recommend instead of mapTo?

Comment: @user3370773: you could use `mapTo` with not generic class (see update). The problem is not in `mapTo` method - you'll get the same problem in `receive` method in actor.